# Animated Splash Screen in android

Tags: android, animation, splash-screen

Hi all I'm trying to figure out how to implement a animated splash screen in android application like [Appy Geek](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobilesrepublic.appygeek&hl=en) application. I tried to use a gif animated pic but it is not animating in android.Then I used android [Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html). Form Drawable Animation I'm able to create a animation but to do that I need sequence pictures (Frame by Frame). I need to know is there any other techniques in android to do this.

Comment: **[Please don't use a splash screen if possible](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/)**

Comment: hm.. its good article. but I need to know how to do this :D

Answer (score 0):

Traditional animation isn't great because you need a bunch of pictures. You can use property animation either via xml or java.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
     anim.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:delay="50%"
            android:animation="@anim/slide_top_to_bottom" />

   and set these to main layout::->

    android:layoutAnimation="@+anim/anim"
```

Comment: can you explain more about this. How to do this where should I put this anim.xml and how to animate the background.

Comment: create folder with anim name and create xml in it and put these code into it and use .